# Two Ruby Seps for Vertical and Horizontal Japanese

Tags: xecjk, japanese

Is it possible to define two different rubysep's (i.e., something like

```
\renewcommand{\rubysep1}
\renewcommand{\rubysep2}
```

one for vertical and the other for horizontal Japanese (which appear in the same document)? I'm using XeLateX with xeCJK and polyglossia (Windows 10, TeXworks).
The reason I'm asking is that the spacing for the vertical case is different from the horizontal layout.

Thanks!

P.S. I have no MWE to present, because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Unless you do something special you can't use numbers in a macro name. Macro names like `\rubysepv` and `\rubyseph` would be OK for the vertical and horizontal marco names.

Comment: Don’t you have to set up an environment for vertical text anyways? You could locally set a different `\rubysep` in the definition for this environment.

Comment: Thank you, Jasper Habicht! I did it, and it works well enough.

Comment: That said, CJKV characters could be part of macro names. For instance `\rubysep二`